# Use one NSManagedObject for UITableView sections and it's relationship to another NSManagedObject for rows?

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, magicalrecord

Is it possible to setup a `UITableView` with `NSFetchedResultsController` as it's `dataSource` where `Contact Group` determines the sections, and `Contact Group`'s to-many relationship with `Person` determines the rows for each section?

So my data model looks like this.

```
Contact Group
 - Person
 - Person
 - Person
Contact Group
 - Person
 - Person
 - Person
```

`Contact Group` is one `NSManagedObject` and it has a to-many relationship with `Person` `NSManagedObjects`. Basically the table view should appear as above as well.

I am using MagicalRecord, if this makes a difference, does this look right?

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (!_fetchedResultsController) {
        _fetchedResultsController = [ContactGroup fetchAllSortedBy:@"displayOrder"
                                                           ascending:YES
                                                       withPredicate:nil
                                                             groupBy:@"SELF.contacts"
                                                            delegate:self];
    }
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Oh, and I need to be able to sort (and persist) the contacts within each section.

Any guidance is appreciated. Please don't hesitate to comment if I need to clarify better.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with Magical Record, but since you mainly want records from Person, you would have to call that method on Person, not ContactGroup:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (!_fetchedResultsController) {
        _fetchedResultsController = [Person fetchAllSortedBy:@"displayOrder"
                                                   ascending:YES
                                               withPredicate:nil
                                                     groupBy:@"contactGroup.groupName"
                                                    delegate:self];
    }
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Comment: But does this get them divided into sections by their 'parent' Contact Group?

Comment: Yep, if the name of that relationship is "contactGroup". If it's something else, change the name of the sectionKeyPath.

Comment: I tried this, but it says: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ContactGroup groupLabel]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8174c20'
***` the groupLabel being the name of the group.

Comment: Oh and one more thing, the reason I was trying to derive the section from `Contact Group`s objects is that if no `Person` objects exist for a particular `Contact Group` the section would not appear, but I want the section to always appear based on the existence of `Contact Group` objects and then the rows based on `Person` objects.

Comment: Please edit the code in your question to what you currently have and include the error message, it's hard to tell without seeing any code. If you go about it this way, empty sections will not show up, though. I'm not sure if that's even possible with Magical Record.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was attempting; that empty sections would show up because the `Contact Group` object exist and it would just have zero rows because no `Person` are related to the `Contact Group`